# Merging a folder with SVN repository

Tags: svn

I have a folder containing subdirectories and files which I want to merge with an SVN repository. How can I do that? Please note that files in the folder which I want to merge can be under different folders. For instance, 
`/folder/dir1/file.cpp` in the folder maybe under 
`/src/dir2/file.cpp` in the repository

Comment: It is not really clear from your question what exactly you are trying to do. What do you mean with "merge" exactly? Adding the files?

Comment: No.. merging the files; i.e., patching the repos with the fixes contained in the "folder"

Comment: Ok, in that case just make a checkout and replace the files in there with the corrected versions you have. For svn this is just like editing the files. Exactly the same. When done simply checkin again.

Comment: Ok, if I replace the file a.cpp in the repos with the file a.cpp in the "folder", I will loose the changes which were committed to a.cpp after the "folder" was checkedout.. Could you please point to a possible solution?

Comment: I want to do this because a.cpp in the "folder" has some fixes.

Comment: Hm, you should mention such things in the question, don't you think so? The answers given below should work. I guess you have your solution... If that does not work (whyever), then I would create patch files from that checkout of the old revision and apply those patches to the checkout of a current head. Might require some manual tweaking...

Answer (score 3):

Preface: you **really have to read** SVN Book!

Because from your description of problem isn't possible to do clear conclusion about initial state I'll describe both choices

## Starting point for both versions

You have:

- `somefile of old version`
- `patched somefile of old version`
- updated `somefile of new version`

## You know revision of `somefile of old version`

Let old revision be **R1**

- Get this revision: `svn co REPO@R1` in case of missing WC, `svn up -r R1` in case of existing WC
- Replace in WC `somefile of old version` by `patched somefile of old version`
- Get other changes: `svn up`. All changes between R1 and HEAD, which appeared in `somefile` will be merged into `patched somefile of old version`: automatically if no conflicts were detected or using merge-tool for manual resolving of conflicts (if merge-tool configured) and, as result, `patched somefile of new version` will appear in WC as not-commited-local-change, which you have to commit in order to save

## You don't know revision of `somefile of old version`

- Using OS diff, generate patch from `somefile of old version` and `patched somefile of old version`
- Get `somefile of new version` (see `svn up` or `svn co`)
- Try to apply patch from p.1 to `somefile of new version`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In scenario (b), if I do not have the revision number of somefile, how can I use OS diff to generate a patch from somefile of old version and patched somefile of old version?

Comment: @Iceman: `diff -u "somefile of old version" "patched somefile of old version" > file.patch`

Comment: I would not have "somefile of old version" if I do not know the version.

Comment: @Iceman: if you have **only** modified file, based on unknown source - forgot about SCM and merging changes

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

Check out the repos into a working copy.  Then move (replace!) the to-be-merged files with the proper files.  Since this is not obvious, you have to do it one-by-one.  When you're done, you can `svn diff` the changes.

( Technically, that is not a merge, but I'm not sure if you really wanted a merge :) )

Comment: Doing this would cause me to loose recent changes committed in the repos which happened after the "folder" was checkedout.

Comment: Ah!  So, it's a merge after all.  Then check out the revision you spawned your version off from.  Do as I said, then do `svn up`, thus receiving all the changes from then (spawn) to now.  After that `svn diff` and/or `svn ci`.

Comment: Yup this is what I was thinking.. replacing files then doing an svn up

Comment: I do an svn up.. it says that it has sync with the latest revision.. but not actually in sync with the latest revision as some latest changes in repos are lost. I am using SVN from Macintosh terminal. Any ideas?

Comment: Not really. Are you sure the "old" revision was correct? Did you handle all conflicts properly? Are you sure you interpret this "latest revision as some latest changes in repos are lost" correctly? How can you know? It can't be from the repos, since that just synced to latest revision.

Comment: Yeah the weird thing is that it never indicated any conflicts. I am tracing the cause..

Answer (score 0):

If the solutions presented in the other answers really don't work for some reason then you might give this a try. Though it is more complex I don't see a reason why it should not work:

- dump revisions 0 to  into a file.
- dump revisions  to  into another file.
- create a new repo and import the first dump.
- make a checkout of that new repos head, replace the files and make a checkin.
- import the revisions of the second dump into the new repo.

That way you inject an additional revision in the middle of a repository. never did that myself, but why not? Just make sure you keep your old repo a while... you never know...